# SSL not work for virtual IP

Tags: linux, networking, ssl, tomcat

I have a website which was deployed with three real web servers and a load balancer with a virtual IP. I have applied an SSL certificate from a CA and imported to Tomcat using OpenSSL using the command like below:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycert.crt -inkey mykey.key \
                        -out mycert.p12 -name tomcat -CAfile myCA.crt \
                        -caname root -chain
```

The command above was executed on all web servers. I also edit my server.xml file under the Tomcat conf/ directory.

```
<Connector 
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="/etc/ssl/myCA.crt" keystorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Ideally, when clicking the "login" button, it should use the https scheme without any warnings/errors.

Now, if I go to each web server
http://real.webserver01.com:8080
and click "login", it goes well without any warnings/errors.
However, if I go to my virtual IP
http://[my virtual ip address]
and click "login",  it still displays the "untrusted connection" page which asks me to manually trust the connection.

What is the problem? Is there anything I missed out?

Comment: Don't know what your load balancer is, but for mine i have to import certificate on the load balancer too

Comment: i am using heartbeat-ldirectord

Answer (score 0):

Your browser compares what you entered in the address bar with the certificate.  The certificate has the full domain name of your site.  The browser compares the IP address with this, and since that fails, the warning is shown.

If you obtain the IP of something like a bank site, and use the IP address to access directly, in most browsers, you'll get the same message.

Try accessing the site from an external location using the full domain name, and see if you still get the message.

Comment: the warning message still occurs when i use my full domain name instead of the virtual ip address. this occurs even if i tried to access the full domain name from internal network (not exactly in the same subdomain [255.255.255.0], but within the same department inside a university [255.255.0.0]).

Comment: maybe i should import certificate on the load balancer, too?

Comment: @fanchyna: that it was what i said in the very first comment about your topic...

Comment: I checked the IT support in our department. The heartbeat-ldirectory runs in a lower level so it does not require to import the certificate. Actually, before our last certificate expired, the https schema was OK without importing the certificate to the load balancer. I think it depends on the load balancer. What is the load balancer are you using, user2196728?